# Will renicing (lower) a process make it faster under memory pressure?

Tags: memory, android, nice

Let's say I want to prioritize a few processes that are running on a device with high memory pressure. These processes are UI processes (Android, specifically) and are running very slowly in this state. When I grep for my process in

```
ps -eo min_flt,maj_flt,cmd
```

I can see that my major page faults are very high (thousands for a UI actions like opening a new Android activity).

If renice my processes to a lower niceness (higher priority), can I expect to see less maj page faults? Increasing priority should give it more CPU resources, but I'm not sure if that will speed up the process if the bottleneck is memory pressure/page faults.

Answer (score 3):

> Increasing priority should give it more CPU resources, but I'm not sure if that will speed up the process if the bottleneck is memory pressure/page faults.

It won't. The `nice` level only affects the scheduler.

With root privileges, you can use `mlockall(MCL_CURRENT|MCL_FUTURE)` to lock mapped pages into RAM. On Linux. I don't know if any such facility is available on Android.

A while back there was a patch that would allow inheriting `mlockall` status across `exec`, which would allow the creating of simple wrapper programs to run any executable with `mlockall`. https://lwn.net/Articles/308552/ Unfortunately, the patch didn't make it into mainline Linux, so you'll have to edit the codez, or if it is a scripting language interpreter, find a way to make a native call to `mlockall`.